# How to parse a huge XML file any not run out of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, gpx

My app can import GPX files (XML) and then I use the wonderful [XML Dictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) library which does a fantastic job of parsing XML and GPX, but in this instance I have an 85MB file that I want to try and parse. It contains over 16,000 GPX waypoints which is huge.

Currently I read an `NSURL` into `NSData` and then use the parser. But I get memory warnings and a crash when trying with the large file.

**How can I chunk the parsing of a large file like this so that I don't get memory errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the XML Dictionary library you are using is that it builds a massive object tree of the whole XML file. This uses a lot of memory.

You are much better off using a SAX parser, such as the standard `NSXMLParser` class. Nothing is kept in memory except whatever data structures you keep as the parsing progresses.

In either case, you don't need to load the whole XML file into memory before parsing. Open a stream to the file and pass the stream to the parser.

Comment: `XML Dictionary` does use `NSXMLParser`. What are they doing different?

Comment: Read the description on the main page of the github project. XML Dictionary is building a huge tree of objects representing the entire XML document. It is all of that extra overhead beyond what `NSXMLParser` is doing that is causing the memory issues. You essentially have 3 copies of the XML file in memory. 1) The full `NSData` of the entire file. 2) The giant tree built by XML Dictionary. 3) Your own data model after processing the parsed XML. #1 can be avoided by open a stream to the XML file instead of loading the whole file into memory. And you can avoid #2 by using just NSXMLParser.

Comment: Are there any helper classes out there that do this? I am finding little information about there about opening a stream using `NSXMLParser` in the way you are mentioning.

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSXMLParser initWithStream:`. Then look at the docs for `NSInputStream`.